# Problem in implementing Quick Look API

Tags: iphone, pdf, quicklook

I want to implement QuickLook API for preview of pdf file. I made a view based app and in .h file I import QuickLook/QuickLook.h . in .m file I made the object of QLPreviewController inside viewDidLoad. After that i tried to make object of QLPreviewItem, but this gives error "QLPreviewItem undeclared". Plz help me if u can.

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your almost there!

the QLPreviewController need a QLPreviewControllerDataSource

implement `<QLPreviewControllerDataSource>`

and add two functions:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1; //number of documents, usually you use a array with document url's
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"document.pdf"]; //other documents are supported too
}
```

Your see that the second method a QLPreviewItem returns (as you see it works with plain URL's too)

I hope I helped you a bit further

Comment: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"apdfdocument.pdf"]` is a very bad way to create a `NSURL` from a path. You should use `-fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: @Julien Thank you, but can you explain me why exactly?

Comment: `-URLWithString:` is meant to create URLs from string conforming to RFC 2396 (so with all the escaping needed, among other things) and is not meant to create file URL with just a path. You are lucky in your example that your file name does not contain any problematic characters, for example.

Comment: More generally, as stated in `-URLWithString:` documentation: "To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` instead." :-)

Answer (score 4):

QLPreviewItem is not a class but a protocol. You must either use NSURLs to fill the API (NSURL conforms to QLPreviewItem) or create your own class of objects conforming to that protocol.

Comment: Can you add an example, please :)